# SQL Server large transaction log for simple recovery model? help!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all i'm building a data warehouse and noticed that my tran log is massive (in simple recovery).  MDF file is 2.6 GB.  LDF file is 7.8 GB!!! Why is this??? i don't want a stupid tran log that's why i've put in simple recovery!  (i know the system needs tran log).  so i tried to shrink the DB and get this error message.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (< DB >)

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE: File ID 1 of database ID 5 was skipped because the file does not have enough free space to reclaim.
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE: File ID 2 of database ID 5 was skipped because the file does not have enough free space to reclaim.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

have plenty of disk space!  ARGH should change my job title to professional sql wrestler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, converting my comment to answer :

If the database is EMPTY, what is the **initial size** of the transaction log defined when the DB was created ?

If the initial size of the T-log is defined more than you need, then thats the problem.

You should always carefully define the transaction logsize.